# How to apply font sizes from combobox to label?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using JavaFX and Scene Builder. 
I have combobox with font sizes and  label in the window.

How to apply chosen size to the label?

```
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;
@FXML  private ComboBox<String> size;

//create array of font sizes
ObservableList<String> fontSizes= FXCollections.observableArrayList("8", "10", 
"11", "12", "14", "16", "18","20", "24", "30", "36", "40", "48", "60", 
72");   


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
   size.setItems(fontSizes);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Strings for your font sizes instead of Integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get you started :

```
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;
@FXML  private ComboBox<String> size;

//create array of font sizes
ObservableList<String> fontSizes= FXCollections.observableArrayList("8", "10",
"11", "12", "14", "16", "18","20", "24", "30", "36", "40", "48", "60",
"72");


@FXML
public void initialize() {
    size.setItems(fontSizes);
    size.setOnAction(e-> updateLabel());
}

private void updateLabel() {
    double fontSize = Double.valueOf(size.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    fontLabel.setFont(  new Font(fontSize ));
}
```

Comment: Actually it would be simpler to use a `ComboBox<Integer>` (or `ComboBox<Double>`). This way you could simply do `fontLabel.setFont(Font.font(size.getValue()));`

Comment: @fabian Your method works! and it is  simpler) thanx!